# Graph divisibility problem

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

For $p$ and $q$ distinct primes.
Two conditions are given:

vertices of graph $G$ are integers in the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, pq-2, pq-1\}$;

there is an edge of graph $G$ between $a$ and $b$ if $ab$ either $p∣a−b$ or $q∣a−b$. In this case, how many edges of $G$ are there?

Comment: @WilliamBallinger Given the repeat, I did a Google search for it, and out pops [Berkeley Homework 6, question 4](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs70/fa13/hw/hw6.pdf). There were also some questions posted from the previous Berkeley homework set too (and were repeated)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the degree of vertex 0? Degree of vertex $n$?

**Hint:** Handshaking Lemma.